# How can I use sharedPreferences in baseAdapter?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I do that?I tried:

```
SharedPreferences spdata = this.getSharedPreferences(
                your file name,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but editor doesn't see **getSharedPreferences...**,**getDefaultSharedPreferences..**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `Context` and then `context.getSharedPreferences()` , you can get it via the adapter's constructor.

Your adapter's constructor:

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
     this.context = context; // assuming you have a local field named context in adapter's class
}
```

In you activity's `onCreate()` or something:

```
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How can I define Context? such as;My SharedPreferences in MainActivity.How do I get?

Comment: okey,I can get in constructor,but I cant use except/without constructor.